# How to check if an int contains a letter

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to validate my code by error checking. I want to make sure the integer people enter does not contain a letter or more.
Here is my code. I am supposed to solve this problem using a one dimensional array. I got the code working but I am having problems with adding the error checking in.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
public void getNumbers() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int array[] = new int[5];
    int count = 0;
    int entered = 0;
    int k = -1;

    while (entered < array.length) {

        System.out.print("Enter a number ");
        int number = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (10 <= number && number <= 100) {

            boolean containsNumber = false;

            entered++;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                if (number == array[i]) // i Or j
                {
                    containsNumber = true;
                }
            }
            if (!containsNumber) {
                array[count] = number;
                count++;
            } else {
                System.out.println(number + " has already been entered");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("number must be between 10 and 100");
        }

        //what does %d do?
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%d ", array[j]);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: if a non-integer is entered, doesn't nextint() throw a inputmismatchexception?

Comment: your code rather check if the value has already been entered

Comment: yes, it throws an exception. I think my instructor doesnt want me to have a exception. another guy in my class said he got it working using hasNextInt

Comment: count = 0; your loop will never execute; and you just have to catch InputMismatchException when reading the entered value

Comment: Your instructor doesn't want you to have an _uncaught_ exception? or your instructor doesn't want you to use exceptions _at all_?  Writing a handler (i.e., `catch` clause) for `NumberFormatException` that tells the user, "invalid number, please try again" would be a very normal way of dealing with invalid inputs.

Comment: Your instructor wants you to use your brain, not that of other people. Not a good fit for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you would want your program to ask the user to re-enter a number if they do not input a number the first time. In this scenario you might want to try something along the lines of this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
while(!sc.hasNextInt()) {
    //print some error statement
    sc.nextLine(); 
}
int number = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Number is: " + number); // to show the value of number
// continue using number however you wish
```

Since `hasNextInt()` returns a boolean determining whether or not the input is an Integer, the program will never leave the while-loop until the program can confirm that the user has entered an integer.

Answer (score 0):

`keyboard.nextInt()` will throw a `InputMismatchException` if you input a String.

If you want to check whether `Scanner` has an integer to read, you can use `keyboard.hasNextInt()`.

Alternatively, you can read the input as 
`String s = keyboard.next()` which will take the input as a String, and then use `s.matches(".*\\d+.*")` to detect whether or not it is an integer.

UPDATE: To answer questions - 
`keyboard.hasNextInt()` will return a boolean. So for example, after `System.out.print("Enter a number")`, you could have an `if` statement checking to see if `keyboard` can receive numerical input, ie. `if(keyboard.hasNextInt)`. If this is true, that means the user has entered numerical input, and you could continue with saying`int number = keyboard.nextInt()`. If it is false, you would know that the user input is non-numerical.

Comment: I'm having a hard time putting the keyboard.hasNextInt() into my code. Do I make an if statement ?

Comment: @Stepsie94 I edited my answer to (hopefully) address this.